# In LaTeX, is there a way to get long lines along the margins?

Tags: latex, lines

I'm working on a report, and some elements are outside the margins (but some are just barely outside the margins). I was wondering: Is there a way to make two vertical lines, one on each side, along the margins so that one can easily see if it goes outside them?

(Googling it, I only found information about margin notes.)

A figure is below:

```
|report text goes here|
|more text goes also h|ere
|and so on and so fort|h
```

It would certainly make correcting these kinds of mistakes very trivial. :)

Feel free to post answers that would solve/show this problem in a more "LaTeX-correct" way, if that makes any sense at all.

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting overfull box warnings when you compile?

Comment: There is a command that places black boxes at such points. If you get a lot of such overfull hboxes you can also try to increase / decrease `\tolerance` to force latex to make the text aligned (at the cost of having sometimes not *quite* nice spaces between words).

Comment: @Jefromi: Yes, but I am too lazy to do it that way. :) The LaTeX output is very noisy in my opinion.

Comment: Context has \showframe, which shows all of the lines superimposed on all pages.  I'm guessing there is nothing equivalent for Latex - I'd be very interested to hear if there was.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the option `draft` in your `\documentclass` statement, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{report}
```

This will produce a litte black box at the end of every overfull line (this is what Johannes Schaub must've been referring to in his comment). This makes it very easy to spot these 
inconvenient overlong lines ...

Alternatively, you can say `\sloppy` in your preamble. The typesetter will then be less strict on the grey value of your paragraphs and avoid "overfull \hbox"es more often (more frequent linebreaking).

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I needed. :) (If I had the reputation points, I would certainly vote your answer up.)

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".
However, your answer was of course accepted. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you're using pdflatex, try the microtype package.

Comment: Huh? Can you elaborate a bit (I'm interested)?

Comment: I meant that using the microtype package usually leads to less overfull lines.